# single-line if statement in a shell script not working

Tags: bash, scripting, if-statement

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat input$1 | ./prog$1 > output$1 && if[ "$2" != "" ]; diff output$1 expected$1;
```

This then happens:

```
$ ./run.sh
./run.sh: line 2: if[ no !=  ]: command not found
$
```

I thought that I could run if statements on one line? is that what the problem is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it turns out that there needs to be a space between the `if` and the `[`. Also, I put in the `then` and `fi` keywords.

The following worked.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat input$1 | ./prog$1 > output$1 && if [ "$2" != "" ]; then diff output$1 expected$1; fi
```

EDIT:

as commented below (and in another answer), this can elegantly be shortened to:

```
cat input$1 | ./prog$1 > output$1 && [ "$2" != "" ] && diff output$1 expected$1
```

in which case I don't even have to remember any of the rules about how to use the `if` construct :)

Comment: You can shorten that a bit: `./prog$1 < input$1 > output$1 && [ "$2" != "" ] && diff output$1 expected$1`

Answer (score 3):

drop the if. [] will spawn a new "command" and you can run diff or whatever after if it exits with 0 using && (run next if previous exits ok). here:

```
echo lol &&  [ $((10-1)) -eq 9 ] && echo math\!
```

and your one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat input$1 | ./prog$1 > output$1 && [ "$2" != "" ] && diff output$1 expected$1
```